# Node js + load html and css files in a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing a node js project here is my project hierarchy.

[image]

Here is my .**njs file**

```
    var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile('./home.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```

But css files are not loaded.Please help me out with the correct coding.Thnx

Comment: This code will send the same response to every request, no matter what the URL.  You need to examine the URL of the request and serve up the correct file or, more realistically, use something like [Express](http://expressjs.com) to handle routing requests and serving static assets (like CSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the 'connect' module very simple to use:

```
var connect = require('connect');    
connect.createServer(
    connect.static(__dirname)
).listen(8000);
```